# tomcat 8.0.27 and System.getProperty("file.separator")

Tags: java, file, tomcat

I've done quite a bit of research but haven't found anyone with similar problem.

```
pathSeparator=System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

I get the file seperator ("/" or "\") via this function.

```
theFile = new java.io.File( this.getServletContext().getRealPath(pathSeparator+"EXAMPLE"+pathSeparator+"EXAMPLE1"+pathSeparator+"EXAMPLE2"+pathSeparator + EXAMPLE3+ ".example") );
```

The above code should getRealPath from the following string:

```
\EXAMPLE\EXAMPLE1\EXAMPLE2\EXAMPLE3.example
```

which it does, but variable theFile is set to null after execution of the code. If I set pathSeperator to "/" then theFile is not null and it works as it should. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it only a copy-error in the question or is it really PathSep**e**rator and PathSep**a**rator?

Comment: @piet.t yes copy-error. I manually wrote it and got it wrong hehe. Now is fixed.

Comment: Hmm, don't see how `theFile` could ever be null after `theFile = new File(...)` unless there is an exception thrown.

Comment: @Henry Yes you are right. I use the same code on multiple occasions. Here I actually get null pointer exception. But if there was String instead of File, theFile would be set to null. Sorry for confusing information

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of ServletContext().getRealPath.

This method returns null if it can not convert the path to real path.

Java and Servlets in particular use **"/"** as path separator for their Virtual path denotation. This is true even on Windows systems.

So using **"\"** is of no value in Servlet context and you will get null from ServletContext().getRealPath if you use that

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At first I thought so as well. But I tried running program on different computers and the problem is only on mine. I'm suspecting it is the version of tomcat server. Will try on different version and will post my findings.